# organize my database results using dropdown list

Tags: php, ajax, oracle, oracle11g

everyone, I'm a newbie and I was trying to organize my database results using 2 drop down lists
what I want is to filter the results depending on what selection the user is making 
I'm using oracle HR database :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showEmp(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","emp.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--END Header-->

        <table>
        <tr>
            <!--Semester-->
            <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">MANAGER ID</td>
            <td><select name="MANAGER_ID" id="M_ID" style="font-weight:bold;" onchange="showEmp(this.value)">
            <option value=""  selected="selected" >select a manager</option>
            <option value="100" >Bob</option>
            <option value="101" >alex</option>
            <option value="103" >Steven</option>
            </select></td>
            <!--Week-->

            <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">DEPARTMENT ID</td>
            <td><select name="dep" id="dep-id"   style="font-weight:bold;" onchange="showEmp(this.value)">
            <form action="">
            <option value="all"  selected="selected" >select a department</option>
            <option value="90" >IT</option>
            <option value="30" >HR</option>
            <option value="100" >finance</option>
            </select>
            </form>
            </td>





        <tr><td align="center" >Emp info</td></tr>

    <div class="container" style="center" id="txtHint" >
    <?php

    $q = intval($_GET['q']);
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = '".$q."'");
    oci_execute($stid);?>
    <table id="report" align="center" width="98%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl" border="0" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center" width="30">EMPLOYEE ID</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">FIRST NAME</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">LAST NAME</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">EMAIL</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">PHONE NUMBER</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">HIRE DATE</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">JOB ID</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">SALARY</td>
    </tr>


    <?php



    while ($row=oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){ 

    ?>
        <tr>        
            <td><?php echo $row['EMPLOYEE_ID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['FIRST_NAME']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['LAST_NAME']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['EMAIL']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['PHONE_NUMBER']; ?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
    }


    ?>

    </table>

    </div><!--end container-->

    </table>
    <br />
```

Comment: you haven't told us what the question is/problem

Comment: your html is incorrect - you have a form tag within the select menu ~ or rather, in and out of the select menu. Actually there are more errors than just that.

Comment: and `<form>` can't be a child of `<table>`.

Comment: Plus, what `<form>` doing inside `<select>`? Now, I am 100% sure, you are a newbie. "*..everyone, I'm a newbie*"

Comment: sorry , I removed it , but getting the error : Undefined index: q

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the html should perhaps be more like this but there are empty table/missing cells or colspans not defined. This doesn't solve the question

```
<?php
    /* Process ajax ~ is this the same page? ie: emp.php or another page? */
    if( !empty( $_GET['MANAGER_ID'] ) ){
        ob_clean();

        $manager_id=$_GET['MANAGER_ID'];

        /* construct your SQL to select from whichever table */
        $sql='select from <TABLE> where <ID>='.$manager_id;

        /* execute query and iterate through recordset to build the menu innerHTML */

        /* echo html to be processed by ajax callback */
        echo $html;


        exit(); 
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function showEmp(str) {
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else { 
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","emp.php?q="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--END Header-->
        <form action="">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <!--Semester-->
                    <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">MANAGER ID</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="MANAGER_ID" id="M_ID" style="font-weight:bold;" onchange="showEmp(this.value)">
                            <option value=""  selected="selected" >select a manager</option>
                            <option value="100" >Bob</option>
                            <option value="101" >alex</option>
                            <option value="103" >Steven</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <!--Week-->
                    <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">DEPARTMENT ID</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="dep" id="dep-id"   style="font-weight:bold;" onchange="showEmp(this.value)">
                            <option value="all"  selected="selected" >select a department</option>
                            <option value="90" >IT</option>
                            <option value="30" >HR</option>
                            <option value="100" >finance</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" >Emp info</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <div class="container" style="center" id="txtHint">
            <?php
                $q = intval($_GET['q']);
                $stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = '".$q."'");
                oci_execute($stid);
            ?>
            <table id="report" align="center" width="98%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl" border="0" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center" width="30">EMPLOYEE ID</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">FIRST NAME</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">LAST NAME</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">EMAIL</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">PHONE NUMBER</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">HIRE DATE</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">JOB ID</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">SALARY</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    while ( $row=oci_fetch_array( $stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS ) ){
                ?>
                <tr>        
                    <td><?php echo $row['EMPLOYEE_ID']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['FIRST_NAME']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['LAST_NAME']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['EMAIL']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['PHONE_NUMBER']; ?></td>
                    <!-- what about the other cells for which there are column headers? -->
                </tr>
                <?php
                }/* close while loop */
                ?>
            </table>
        </div><!--end container-->
    </body>
</html>
```

### example

```
<?php
    /*
        -------
        emp.php
        -------
    */
    /* include database connection */
    include 'dbconn.php';

    if( isset( $_GET['q'] ) ){

        /* Filter by ONE field */
        $var=$_GET['q'];

        /* construct your sql */
        $sql='select * from <TABLE> where <COL>="'.$var.'"';

        /* empty array to store generated html */
        $html=array();

        /* query the db */
        $result=$db->query( $sql );
        /* Iterate through recordset */

        while( $row=$result->fetch() ){
            /* add html to array */
            $html[]="<option value='".$row->FIELD_NAME_ID."'>".$row->FIELD_NAME_STRING;
        }
        /* close db connection */
        $db->close();

        /* send data back to ajax callback */
        echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );

        exit();
    }

?>

search.php
----------
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example pseudo code and method explanation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
            here is YOUR html with the select menus
            The select menus have an `onchange` event
            handler which sends a request to `emp.php`

            `emp.php` is sent, by the ajax function 1
            parameter - called `q`

            emp.php must process the querystring / GET 
            request variables to generate the sql that is
            used to build the html content that will be used
            by the AJAX callback function to populate the div
            with ID "txtHint"

            Ideally the AJAx request would use POST rather than GET
            but that might just be a personal preference in situations
            like this.

            Assume this page is called "search.php" and has the db
            connections and works OK.
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error : Undefined index: q , do you know why?

Comment: The code I posted was more to show how your HTML might be corrected. The `undefined index` error is because of the php at the very top. If you delete that PHP then at least I hope the page should load properly ( if you supply a `q` parameter in the querystring ) - which just leaves you needing to create the code for `emp.php` which you neglected to share initially.

Comment: done thank you , one more question please , how can I filter the data using 2 drop down lists or more instead of one?

Comment: in the php script, `emp.php`, you need to grab the variables sent - via ajax - to the script and use them to construct your sql. As both select menus have an `onchange` event handler you will only be passing one variable at a time unless you include the value from both select menu's in the ajax function or use some sort of storage ( cookies, sessions etc ) to keep track of parameters sent via ajax. The required explanation is too long for a comment.

Comment: and why when I put the option value a string value the code don't work? for example If I wanted to filter using the job title?

Answer (score 0):

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a salary:</option>
  <option value="17000">17000</option>
  <option value="9000">9000</option>
  <option value="4800">4800</option>
  <option value="7700">7700</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

php code:
    
    
    
    
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

```
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

    $conn = oci_connect('hr', 'hr123', 'Glory-PC:1521/XE');
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE SALARY= '".$q."'");
                oci_execute($stid);


echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";
while($row=oci_fetch_array( $stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS )) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FIRST_NAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LAST_NAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['EMAIL'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PHONE_NUMBER'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['HIRE_DATE'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```